# colorbox и переменные

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Проблема такая:
Вызываю модальное окно через colorbox и в этом модальном окне срабатывает ready, которая должна прочитать атрибут одного элемента, но проблема в том что ready находится в самом низу страницы, а пытается читать его, когда сам попап еще не прогрузился. Ну и выходит, что значения переменной нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В алерт должно быть значение атрибута, который расположен выше самого алерта
Пробовал использовать holdready - не помогло. 
Может кто сталкивался...

И да. Пытался цеплять за событие colorbox-а onComplete - так же пока что безуспешно...

Решил:

```
$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
 ///// тут мой код
});
```